# Difference between Document Library and Form Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, document-library, forms-library

What is the difference between Document Library and Form Library? In which scenario we have to go for Form Library? And What are the best practices of using these libraries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Document Libraries** in SharePoint consist of your main/core documents. For example a word document, excel, PowerPoint, Visio, pdf, csv, notepad etc.

**Form libraries** consist of XML forms (InfoPath Forms).

The scope of answer will very huge as there are so many different scenario. But major difference is

**Document Library** is used to maintain the documents and **Form Library** is used to maintain the Forms (InfoPath Forms)

- **Form Library**

If you want detail description about in which scenario we should go with Form Library then please go through this

[Comparing SharePoint List and Form Library Forms](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/infopath/2010/04/22/comparing-sharepoint-list-and-form-library-forms/)

From here you can get the idea about when to use Form Library.

- **Document Library**

And for detailed information about scenarios where to use Document Library you can go through

[Top 10 Best Practices for Document Libraries](http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint-administration/top-10-best-practices-document-libraries)

From here you can get the best functionality provided by the Document Library and if your requirement falls under any of the functionality then you can go through the **Document Library**

Let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

**Document Library:**. It is used for storing documents.

**Form Library:** . It is used for storing InfoPath forms.

Source:
http://www.bizsupportonline.net/blog/2014/what-is-sharepoint-form-library.htm